# Может ли статический метод класса быть экспортруемым?

Tags: c++

Насколько я знаю, для методов экземпляров класса используется thiscall, и они не экспортируются с другими соглашениями. А поскольку статический метод к экземпляру класса не относится, может быть, к нему можно применять другие соглашения, как stdcall и cdecl вместе с dllexport?

Comment: Любой метод может быть экспортируемым

Comment: Что значит "применять другие соглашения"? Откуда в вашем случае вообще возникла необходимость говорить о каких-то "соглашениях"? В чем вы видите какие-то непонятности с экспортированием и почему такой вопрос вообще возник?

Comment: @VTT, эмм.. а как thiscall воспримет "та" сторона? Мне, например, надо для C# работать с соглашениями cdecl или на край stdcall, поскольку thiscall и fastcall он не поддерживает. Могу я принудительно указать эти соглашения методу класса С++?

Comment: @AnT, для использования этих функций из .NET

Comment: @Ant, чуть чуть подправил вопрос. Надеюсь, более точно

Comment: из .NET нельзя использовать с++ методы, только С. Ну или пилить обертку на C++/Cli. На 64 битной VC++ соглашение о вызовах только одно